# Code to show the member count and account creation date whenever a member joins no longer works

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I had had a bot that had the feature to show the member count and user account creation date whenever a new user joins a welcome channel along with a message, and it used to work fine, but after being away from discord for about 6 months and coming back yesterday, I found out that it didn't work anymore, but I can't figure out what changes I have to make to the code :(, can anybody help me out?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const PREFIX = "?";

const fs = require('fs');
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    if(!channel) return;

    channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}, please read the rules in #rules! Subsequently, please introduce yourself in #introductions and provide your timezones.`)

    let dateFormat = require('dateformat')
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("__**Details**__")
  .setColor(0xAAEDF9)
  .setAuthor(`${member.user.tag} Has Joined.`, member.user.displayAvatarURL,)
  .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
  .addField('*Account created*', dateFormat(member.user.createdAt, "mm:dd:yyyy h:MM"), true)
  .addField('\u200B','\u200B')
  .addField('*Member Count*', member.guild.memberCount, true)
channel.send(embed);

});
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What errors are you getting? can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: it doesn't show any errors, but now nothing happens when a user joins the welcome channel

Comment: It will be useful to add some log or toast in your code to help you debug this issue

Answer (score 1):

Discord has very recently applied changes to how certain privacy sensitive user data is sent. Presence and activity data (.presence) as well as events based around guild members (guildMemberAdd, guildMemberRemove, guildMemberUpdate, presenceUpdate) are now explicitly opt-in by either toggling in the developer dashboard

You need to enable the members intent from the discord developers portal

1. Go to the discord developer portal
2. Select your bot application
3. Select bot option
4. Scroll down under privileged intents enable both of them

Comment: If your issue was solved please click the tick option on the answer